# Перенос раздела в Ubuntu на другой жёсткий диск

Tags: ubuntu, раздел

При установке Ubuntu 18.04 по ошибке создал */boot* и */boot/efi* на разных жёстких дисках.

Через GParted создал раздел того же размера. При попытке перекопирывания с помощью Clonezilla в режиме "device device", выбирая "part to local part", вылезает окно с выбором исходного локального раздела. Единственный доступный - sda2. После выбора вылезает ошибка о том, что исходный раздел не существует
[image]
[image]

Comment: Сделай через `gparted` раздел того же размера, который хочешь перетащить, а потом с помощью Clonezilla перекопируй в режиме `local part to local part`.

Comment: Создал раздел того же размера. При попытке перекопирывания в Clonezilla в режиме "device device", выбирая "part to local part", вылезает окно с выбором исходного локального раздела. Единственный доступный - sda2. После выбора вылезает ошибка о том, что исходный раздел не существует:    "Ошибка! Существующи(й/е) раздел(ы) или размонтированны(й/е) раздел(ы) не найден(ы)! Для использования Clonezilla для сохранения или клонирования раздела, исходный раздел должен существовать или быть размонтирован! Если вы уверены, что раздел существует на этом компьютере, возможно ядро слишком старо?..."

Comment: Ненене. Clonezilla не надо устанавливать. Её надо с флэшки прогружать. На оф сайте есть iso. Воспользуйся им.